# Obfuscated application run slow

Tags: c#, obfuscation, confuserex

I'm using ConfuserEX for obfuscate my application. Actually I'm using the maximum preset and the compress functionality to add 4 dlls to my exe.
When I start the app without obfuscation run very fast, but after the obfuscation the start is very slow.
Why happen this? How can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues/624

Comment: @maccettura in my case even disabling the windows defender real time protection run fast, so the issue maybe is not related to the watermark

Comment: @user9493290 I am sure your issue was not related to Windows Defender. Did you ever resolved the issue? As I am facing same issue.